# Improperly Configured urls.py during Django deployment (Django 2.1)

Tags: django

This is my first time deploying Django. My app runs fine locally, but when I deploy, I get this error:

> ImproperlyConfigured at /admin/
>   The included URLconf module 'search.urls' from '/home/imeaytbc/myproject/search/urls.py' does not
>   appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the
>   file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

My `urls.py` file is exactly the same as the one run on my computer:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = 'search'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.query_search, name='query_search'), 
    path('article/<int:ArticleID>/', views.article_detail, name='article_detail')
]
```

Is there anything I need to change in regards to deployment? All the changes I made to my files regarding deployment are about static and media file directories. What else do I need to change for deployment? As far as I am aware, I have uploaded all files to the hosting server and the app shouldn't be missing any file.

EDIT: added main urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('search/', include('search.urls')),]
```

Comment: Can you post your main URLconf? The error is not caused by the urls in your search app but is caused in the main app url where you have included the url of the search app `something like include(search.urls)`

Comment: @Sanip added =)

Comment: Since patterns are defined, the error message may be right about a circular import. This line is too broad: `from . import views` it will import everything that .py imports as well as the views defined in it.  

Consider eliminating possible circular imports taken from your views.py by limiting the import to: `from app_name.views import query_search, article_detail` and use those directly in your patterns.

Comment: @Rob i think that was the issue =) it works now